# Не выводится background картинка, при запуске через Prepros, всё ок, на гите не выводит

Tags: html, css, scss

https://maximys5582.github.io/Piercing.krd/
Вот ссылка на сайт, не знаю в чём проблема честно, помогите пожалуйста

```
<header class="header" id="header">
                <div class="header__image">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="header__row">
                            <div class="header__menu">
                                <div class="header__adress">
                                    <div class="number">+7 (996) 410-41-73</div>
                                    <div class="street">г.Краснодар, ул.Чапаева 69</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="header__item">
                                    <a href="#aboutUs" class="items">О нас</a>
                                    <a href="#gallary" class="items">Галерея</a>
                                    <a href="#staff" class="items">Наши мастера</a>
                                    <a href="#map" class="items">Контакты</a> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://vk.com/piercing_tattoo_krd" class="header__btn">Записаться</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
```

```
.header {
  min-width: 100%;
  font-size: calc(16px + 0.1041666667vw);
}
.header__eqweqwe {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.header__image {
  background: url("/img/image_1.jpg") no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0 250px 0;
}
.header__menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0 74px;
  position: relative;
}
.header__adress {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: calc(12px + 0.2083333333vw);
}
.header__item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 60px;
}
.header__item a {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.header__btn {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: black;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.header__btn:hover {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 10px #000;
          box-shadow: 0 4px 10px #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.header__btn:active {
  background-color: rgb(146, 148, 38);
}

.items {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Comment: Поправьте [адрес картинки](https://github.com/maximys5582/Piercing.krd/blob/main/css/style.css#L112). В браузере есть очень полезная штука под названием инструменты разработчика. И там видно что картинка грузится с неверного адреса.

Comment: Спасибо огромное